# Curl from Pastebin messes with carriage returns

Tags: macos, command-line

Whenever I use curl to get a file like .profile from Pastebin, the .profile file isn't read properly. I did some checking, and it seems to be down to the carriage returns.

How do I solve this problem? Can I correct the carriage returns in transit?

Comment: Can you add some details on how you actually use `curl` here and what the issue with the CRs is?

Comment: Could you add the actual command you are running and what the contents of the pastebin might be.

Comment: You can find the actual command further down the page, if without the filename.

Comment: I forgot to add, I see no difference in the output when I cat the file, but when I source it, I see several error messages (when not including --crlf).

Answer (score 4):

For reasons that pass understanding pastebin.com raw mode uses Windows line endings - carriage return followed by linefeed - rather than plain linefeed that is used by all right thinking operating systems.

So you need to remove the carriage returns. The easiest way to do this is using `tr`.

```
curl https://pastebin.com/raw/qg0r3wt | tr -d '\r' > .profile
```

That will save the contents of the pastebin `qg0r3wt` into the file `.profile` with carriage returns removed.

Comment: If you don't mind a friendly observation, my solution is shorter.

Answer (score -1):

The answer is to include the option --crlf in the command.

```
curl -o .profile --crlf https://pastebin.com/raw/...
```

Comment: That's unlikely to be the answer since the man page for `curl` says that that option is only for upload and only for FTP and SMTP transfers.

Comment: Then maybe we have different versions of curl. It works fine at my end.

Comment: I didn't work with curl v7.68.0 in Ubuntu